# Barbuttonitem tint color can't be changed on one viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, ios11, xcode9, tint

I have two view controllers accessed by tabbarcontrollers and one subview with show detail segue from both main view controllers. The first/intro view controller has blue (default) barbuttonitem text. When you go to the subview immediately from the first/intro controller, the barbuttonitem text remains blue (default). But, when you go to the second viewcontroller, it has black barbuttonitem text. Then, when you go back to the first view controller and then into the subview, the text that was blue (default) previously now becomes black.

[image]

I have tried setting the tint color without success in the ViewDidLoad of all viewcontorllers like this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = nil
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = nil
```

Where can I go from here?

Comment: You sure you didn't set the right bar button to black somewhere?

Comment: I spent over 2 hours yesterday scanning all of the view controllers for something telling it to be black - can't find anything. I also looked through the storyboard to see if it was set there somehow, but no luck. Really scratching my head here.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out! This is a strange one...

On my initial view controller (intro view above), I had the following code at the bottom of viewDidLoad to adjust the color of the "cancel" text for the search bar:

```
let cancelButtonAttributes: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes as? [String : AnyObject], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Factors that made this difficult to debug:

1. This code was on the one view controller that seemed to be working properly, rather than the ones that were broken
2. This code adjusted the cancel button of the search bar, which would seem to have nothing to do with the actual navigation controller. On closer inspection, the code is actually adjusting the appearance of the UIBarButtonItem.